# Codemirror: Retrieve character index from span tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, codemirror

So I have a codemirror instance on the left of a document, and an iframe on the right. When the code is updated in the editor, it is written to the iframe.

During this rewrite, I add an index to each and every element that is created using jQuery's $.data function so that whenever the user hovers their mouse over the element it can be highlighted in the editor.

So far I have managed to pick out the required element's position in the editor in terms of where its generated `<span class="cm-tag cm-bracket">` tag is and give it a class of `cm-custom-highlight`.

My question is - is there any way to turn an instance of a source span tag into an actual selection within the editor?

***Update:*** Answered my own question - see below! You can check out my resulting code [here](https://github.com/boylett/Codemirror-Element-Inspector).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answered my own question! How about that?

Turns out CodeMirror has a neat little list of nodes in its `display` container. All I needed to do was loop through `CodeMirror.display.renderedView[lineNumber].measure.map` and test each text node's `parentNode` property to see if it was the same as the `span` I had highlighted.

The `map` array is structured like so:

```
[
    0: 0
    1: 1
    2: text
    3: 1
    4: 5
    ...
]
```

Every `text` node here refers to a piece of code in the editor and the numbers before and after refer to its character index, so it was pretty easy to find the index that I needed:

```
var span = $('span.cm-custom-highlight', CodeMirror.display.lineDiv),
    lineNumber = span.closest('.CodeMirror-line').closest('div[style]').index(),
    lineView = CodeMirror.display.renderedView[lineNumber].measure.map,
    char = 0;

for(var i in lineView.measure.map)
{
    if(!char &&
        typeof lineView.measure.map[i] == 'object' &&
        lineView.measure.map[i].parentNode && span[0] == lineView.measure.map[i].parentNode)
    {
        char = lineView.measure.map[i - 1];
    }
}
```

Sure it's a little messy, but it gets the job done nicely.

Answer (score 0):

You will get better results when using [`markText`](http://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#markText) rather than directly messing with the editor's DOM. The DOM and view data structure aren't part of the interface, and will change between versions. The editor can also update its DOM at any moment, overriding the changes you made.